# Outlook Add-In becomes inactive after Windows Update

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I have written an Outlook add-in (VSTO in C#) and now the problem occurs that on some machines (all Windows 7) with Office 2010 installed the Outlook add-in suddenly becomes inactive after a Windows Update (including at least one Office update).

It can be reactivated without any issues though and everything will be working fine, including the user-settings.

Do you know what could cause this behavior?

Thanks.